# Using excel to add a table in Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm creating a tool in Excel
Which is going to read in some data and the create a word document based on that data.

So far I've got excel to create the word document and add a few lines of text without any issue.
The next bit though to add a table is causing issues.
I can add the table in fine, but for some reason it deletes the lines of text that I added in the first place.

This is my code:

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSelection As Object
Dim objRange As Object
Dim objTable As Object
Dim ctr as long
            
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
            
Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objRange = objDoc.Range

'Adding some heading Text   
objSelection.Style = objDoc.Styles("Heading 1")
objSelection.Font.Bold = True    
objSelection.TypeText ("Heading Text")
objSelection.TypeParagraph

'Adding some normal Text
objSelection.Style = objDoc.Styles("Normal")
objSelection.Font.Bold = False    
objSelection.TypeText ("Normal Text")
objSelection.TypeParagraph

Stop 

'Adding the table    
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 10, 2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow

objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False
Set objWord = Nothing
```

I put in a stop points after my heading and normal text are added and they appear in the word document fine.(screenshot below)

But as soon as the code reaches the Tables.Add bit, all my text disappears and the document has nothing but the table. (also screenshot below)

I looked around online and tried putting
objSelection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd

before the Tables.Add line of code, but that didn't help.
[image: Screenshot at Stop point]

[image: Screenshot After Table is added]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to add a table fails because you are adding the table into `objRange` which you defined as the entire document.

You should also get into the habit of avoiding use of the `Selection` object, both in Word and Excel. Not only is it ineffecient (the screen has to be redrawn constantly) it is also error prone as the selection could be changed by the user to something you're not expecting.

The code below should work for you.

```
   Dim objWord As Word.Application
   Dim objDoc As Word.Document
   Dim objRange As Word.Range
   Dim objTable As Word.Table
   Dim ctr As Long
            
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWord.Visible = True
            
   Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add

   'Adding some heading Text
   With objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
      .Style = objDoc.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Text = "Heading Text"
      .InsertParagraphAfter
   End With

   'Adding some normal Text
   With objDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range
      .Style = objDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
      .Font.Bold = False
      .Text = "Normal Text"
      .InsertParagraphAfter
   End With

   Set objRange = objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
   'Adding the table
   Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, 10, 2, _
      DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
      AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow)

   objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False
   Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: with that solution how would i add extra empty lines and page breaks? I had been using

"objSelection.TypeParagraph"

to add an extra line and

"objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak"

to add a page break

Comment: @MichaelLiew -  step through the code and you will see how how paragraphs are added.  Make use of the Object Browser, Intellisense and Help to learn what you can do with a range, e.g. [add a page break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertbreak)

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, thanks Timothy
That works really well and much better control than what I was doing

Answer (score 0):

I did the test with the code below and it works :
Pre requisite : add reference "Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library" in your VBA project

```
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

    ' create an instance of MS Word
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    WordApp.Visible = True   
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

    Range("A1:A2").Copy

    WordApp.Selection.TypeText ("Here are my comment")
    WordApp.Selection.Paste
    ' fit the table with window
    WordDoc.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    ' Save the content into the .doc file
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 ("C:\mypath\myDocument.doc")
```